# VB.NET: Inheriting from case-insensitive dictionary type

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, case-insensitive

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I want to create a simple class which inherits from a case-insensitive dictionary type. I can inherit from a case-*sensitive* dictionary type as follows:

```
Public Class clsMyDictionary
  Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

A case-*insensitive* dictionary object is normally created as follows:

```
Dim d = New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

So I would like to do something like the following, so my dictionary class functions as case-insensitive, but it results in a syntax error:

```
Public Class clsMyDictionary
  Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
End Class
```

Specifying StringComparer isn't allowed in that context. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the base constructor with the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter.

```
Public Class clsMyDictionary
  Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)

  public sub new()
     MyBase.New(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  end sub

End Class
```